# How to install google page speed module on Nginx bitnami wordpress in GCP

Tags: debian

How to install google page speed module on Nginx bitnami wordpress(debian) in GCP.. do i need to re-install nginx for installing Page speed module? I have low coding knowledge

trying from 2 days.. not able to setup this .. please help to configure this

Answer (score 0):

Google PageSpeed module has last been updated in July 2020. There have been several nginx releases after that.

If you are lucky, you can built a version of recent nginx with pagespeed module. But still, building it requires some familiarity in building software from source.

Considering all things, I think you shouldn't go this way.

Comment: Can you please help to install nginx pagespeed module.. i am on google Cloud bitnami wordpress .. Debian os.. please guide

Comment: I cannot do that, it is too complex operation if you have no experience in building software from source.